# SSH fingerprint of local daemon

Tags: ssh

Suppose my machine has a SSH daemon running. How do I get its fingerprint without having to  create a network connection?

Meaning to say, without the use of `ssh-keyscan`.

Answer (score 1):

Those keys (returned by [`ssh-keyscan`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-keyscan.1.html)), are [detailed here](https://serverfault.com/a/1021441/783), are in `/etc/ssh/*.pub` of the server.

So unless you have a program on the server ready to send them to you on its own, some kind of network connection would be required to fetch them.

Comment: Thanks, while I don't think I'm qualified, I'm exploring ways to balance between a simple mechanism and MITM attacks. Suppose I connect to 3 different webservers (under my control) via HTTPS to request they connect to the new server, does it sound "safer" or safe enough if they all return the same fingerprint?

Comment: @bilogic It should be safe enough indeed. I would check that with https://security.stackexchange.com/ though.

Comment: just did, thanks! https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248882/preventing-mitm-for-a-new-ssh-daemon